# extracting the word from the string ignoring symbols and numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to extract the word from a string but it should ignore all the symbols and numbers in between if any.

```
string = C#%3HA#*$03IR
```

I want to extract the word `CHAIR` from the above string. Ignore all symbols and numbers.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I feel a regular expression coming up...

Comment: @WoutervanVegchel - no need for regex :)

Comment: Now I'm curious :) Tell me the secret @GiladGreen

Comment: @WoutervanVegchel Have a look at the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply make it using `Regex` class available inside `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RemoveSpecialCharactersConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string line = "C#%3HA#*$03IR";
            line = RemoveSpecialCharacters(line);
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            Console.Read();
        }

        public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string input)
        {
            Regex r = new Regex("(?:[^a-z]|(?<=['\"])s)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);
            return r.Replace(input, string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A string is a collection of `char` so by using linq's `Where` you can query all those that are [`char.IsLetter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletter(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string str = "C#%3HA#*$03IR";
string result = new string(str.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray());
```

You can do it this way too:

```
string result = String.Concat(str.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z -]");
str = rgx.Replace(str, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings in C# are like arrays, so you can loop through all the characters of a string and check if they are letters or not using:

```
Regex reg = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
```

and accordingly you can keep or remove them from array(string).